# Use data from Event Hub Trigger to SQL Connector using Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to store every incoming Event Hub data(JSON) into an Azure SQL Database using Azure Logic Apps. For this I'm using "**Receive Event Hub Message**" as trigger and **Microsoft SQL Connector** as Action.

After entering the details for SQL Connector, I chose "Insert into myTable(JSON)". I tried to assign the data from Event Hub to the table values using **@triggers().outputs.body.[my_param]** (got from git EventHubAPI-README.md), but the table doesn't get updated. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the updated SDK for the Logic Apps, now you have new Actions under SQL Azure (Insert Row, Update Row) and more recently "Execute Stored Procedure" was also made available in the logic app preview